# Is it possible to store the results of a mixin in a variable?

Tags: sass, mixins

I've created a mixin called `my-gradient`...

```
@mixin my-gradient($outerColor, $centerColor) {
    background: $outerColor; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  $outerColor 0%, $centerColor 50%, $outerColor 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,$outerColor), color-stop(50%,$centerColor), color-stop(100%,$outerColor)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  $outerColor 0%,$centerColor 50%,$outerColor 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  $outerColor 0%,$centerColor 50%,$outerColor 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  $outerColor 0%,$centerColor 50%,$outerColor 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  $outerColor 0%,$centerColor 50%,$outerColor 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='$outerColor', endColorstr='$outerColor',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

I can use it fine from my **_structure.scss** file in my css declarations - for example...

```
.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button):hover {
    @include my-gradient($topbar-bg-color, scale-color($topbar-bg-color, $lightness: 50%));
}
```

But is it possible to include it in my **_settings.scss** file. Something a bit like...

```
$body-bg: my-gradient(#fff, #eee);
```

...but something that works??

Comment: You do understand what a mixin is, right?  It doesn't return values.

Comment: I was wondering if there was some function built into Foundation that could enable the mixin to be used in _settings.scss. Seemingly not.

Comment: The problem is not the file, but how you are intending to use the mixin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixins and functions are not interchangeable things.  Mixins do not return values and cannot have their results stored in a variable, only functions can do that.

If all you want is to store the arguments to your mixin as a variable that you an reuse elsewhere, then you can use the [variable arguments](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_arguments) (`...`) syntax when calling the mixin:

```
$body-bg: #fff, #eee; // list of arguments in the exact order they should be sent to the mixin

.foo {
    @include my-gradient($body-bg...);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$body-bg: my-gradient(#fff, #eee);
```

...you are not including a mixing, you are trying to use an non-existing function (since you've defined a [mixin](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins), not a [function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#functions)).

The key thing here is:

- Be aware of where you've defined your mixin.
- Make sure the mixin definition is **before** your intended use.
- If your definition is in a different file as your use (which I guess so, I suspect you didn't define it in _settings.scss) make sure you **import** the file with the mixin definition before you import _settings.scss

You'd then use it like in your example:

```
.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button):hover { @include my-gradient($topbar-bg-color, scale-color($topbar-bg-color, $lightness: 50%)); }
```

However, as another comment states, mixins don't return values, so you can't store them in variables.

What you can do, instead, is use a [placeholder](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders):

```
     %my-placeholder-for-gradients {
    @include my-gradient($topbar-bg-color, scale-color($topbar-bg-color, $lightness: 50%));
 }

.some-real-selector {
    @extend %my-placeholder-for-gradients;
}
```

That would be equivalent to a variable, you could `@extend` that placeholder as many times as you wish (with no duplicated code in the compiled CSS, as opposed as using `@include` repeated times)